# Finish page sometimes showing reboot option even after customized the the screen to show title and description in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I customized my Finish page like as shown below in MyEnglish.nsh file.

```
LangString Finishpagetitle ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Completed the ${ApplicationName} Setup Wizard"
LangString Finishpagesubtitle ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Click the Finish button to exit the Setup Wizard"
```

And written the below code in my MainFile.ini file like as shown below:

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!define MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_TITLE $(Finishpagetitle)
!define MUI_TEXT_FINISH_INFO_TEXT $(Finishpagesubtitle)
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN ""
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```

Normally I am seeing the finish dialog with the above customized title and text.

But sometimes, I am getting the different Finish window with below text:

"Your computer must be restarted in order to complete the installation of $(^NameDA). Do you want to reboot now?"

with two radio buttons "Reboot now" and "I want to manually reboot later"

Why it is showing the reboot dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `/RebootOK` switch on some of the file commands and the installer detects that a file is locked it will ask the user to reboot.

Comment: Wow... It is true. Thank you for your input. I found the root cause based on your solution. I am using the command RMDir /r /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR to remove the directory (If it exists) before installation starts in the beginning of the section. I think i should not use that in the beginning of the section. I removed that line and now it is not showing the reboot dialog. Once again thank you very much.